# Compute angles of direction

Tags: opengl, math, camera, angle

I followed a [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/) to be able to rotate the view in my OpenGL game with the mouse.
I have to admit that I copy-and-pasted without really understanding and that's what I got...

The direction of the camera is computed by the yaw and the pitch:

```
directionX = cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle);
directionY = sin(verticalAngle);
directionZ = cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle);
```

Now I want to reverse the computation and get the angles out of the direction.
I know how to compute the vertical angle:

```
verticalAngle = asin(directionY);
```

But I have no idea how to get the horizontal angle... I tried to rearrange the equation of the x component, but, as expected, it did not work (cause that would mean you don't need the z component to calculate the horizontal angle, which does not make sense).

Can someone show me the equation (maybe explain how to rearrange the equations / how it generally works)? I have no idea what I have to search for on Google/SA

It still does not work, the vertical angle is switching between two values every frame, and I can't turn 360° with the horizontal angle. Here is my code:

```
double elapsed;
frameTime = glfwGetTime();
elapsed = frameTime - lastFrameTime;

int winw, winh;
glfwGetWindowSize(window, &winw, &winh);

double mouseX, mouseY;
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &mouseX, &mouseY);
glfwSetCursorPos(window, winw/2, winh/2);

// compute angles
float preAsinf = camDir[0] / cosf(camAngles[1]);
if (preAsinf < -1) preAsinf = -1;
if (preAsinf > 1) preAsinf = 1;
camAngles[0] = asinf(preAsinf);
camAngles[1] = atan2f(camDir[0], camDir[2]) * cos(camAngles[1]);
printf("%g\n", camAngles[0]);

// compute view
double dmx = (mouseX - winw/2);
double dmy = (mouseY - winh/2);
camAngles[0]+= elapsed * dmx;
camAngles[1]+= elapsed * dmy;

camDir[0] = cosf(camAngles[1]) * sinf(camAngles[0]);
camDir[1] = sinf(camAngles[1]);
camDir[2] = cosf(camAngles[1]) * cosf(camAngles[0]);
kmVec3Normalize((kmVec3 *) camDir, (kmVec3 *) camDir);

// horiAngle - 3.14 / 2 means horiAngle - 90°, which is the right
camRight[0] = sin(camAngles[0] - 3.14f/2.0f);
camRight[1] = 0;
camRight[2] = cos(camAngles[0] - 3.14f/2.0f);
kmVec3Normalize((kmVec3 *) camRight, (kmVec3 *) camRight);

kmVec3Cross((kmVec3 *) camUp, (kmVec3 *) camRight, (kmVec3 *) camDir);
kmVec3Normalize((kmVec3 *) camUp, (kmVec3 *) camUp);

float camCenter[3];
kmVec3Add((kmVec3 *) camCenter, (kmVec3 *) camPos, (kmVec3 *) camDir);
kmMat4LookAt((kmMat4 *) view, (kmVec3 *) camPos, (kmVec3 *) camCenter, (kmVec3 *) camUp);

// compute end matrix
kmMat4Multiply((kmMat4 *) tmp, (kmMat4 *) projection, (kmMat4 *) view);
kmMat4Multiply((kmMat4 *) tmp, (kmMat4 *) tmp, (kmMat4 *) model);
glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderUniforms.transform, 1, GL_FALSE, tmp);
```

The vectors are just arrays, [0] ^= x component, [1] ^= y component.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
horizontalAngle = atan2(directionX, directionZ);
```

this will return an angle between -Pi and + Pi. (The factor `cos(verticalAngle)` cancels out.)

Comment: Can you explain that to me, or show me a way of learning how to do "that kind of stuff" with angles and vectors, hard to google that :D. And if I rotate the view around a bit, I eventually get NANs, probably because of zeros, how can I handle that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions. You can get NANs with the arcsin; clamp the argument to [-1,+1].

Comment: @Kapichu the area of mathematics you want to look into is called Trigonometry; Wikipedia has a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

```
directionX == cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle)
```

Divide by `cos(verticalAngle)`.

```
directionX / cos(verticalAngle) == sin(horizontalAngle)
```

Take the `asin` of both sides.

```
asin(directionX / cos(verticalAngle) == horizontalAngle
```

Flip the equation around, and there's the result.

```
horizontalAngle = asin(directionX / cos(verticalAngle))
```

You don't need to use Z to recover `horizontalAngle`, because the Z component doesn't have any information that you can't recover from X and Y alone. This is because the camera direction vector is a [unit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), so Z = sqrt(1 - X^2 - Y^2).

Comment: I think this does not work because you loose information about the sign.